# Issue with converting date to a specific format

Tags: php, date

I have a date string value that changes everytime , sometimes it is for instance:

```
'14-30-06'
'30/06/2014'
'06/30/2014'
'30-06-14'
...
```

how can I do in PHP to convert the date I get whatever format it has to this format : m/d/Y ?

here is the code that I'm using and that did not work, I get 01/01/1970

```
$date = "14-30-06";
$dtFormat = "m/d/Y";
echo date($dtFormat, strtotime($date));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Use http://php.net/date_create_from_format. strtotime can be magical sometimes, but it's NOT omniscient, and if you're throwing randomish-garbage at it, don't be surprised if you get garbage back out.

Comment: ...GIGO *as the 'ol saying goes.*

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23087239/250259) explains how to do what you need

Comment: my issue is that I do not know the format of the date I have but I do know the format to convert to.